# SingleStore 1.0.1 JDBC ResultsetMetadata returns type name VARSTRING while getColumns returns VARCHAR

Tags: singlestore

JDBC version 1.0.1
Server version 7.6

A table defined as follows

```
create table TVCHAR ( RNUM integer not null , CVCHAR varchar(32 ) null , SHARD KEY ( RNUM ) ) ;
```

DatabaseMetadata.getColumns returns a type name of VARCHAR(32).

When a query `select * from TVCHAR` is executed, the ResultsetMetadata returned by the driver describes the column CVCHAR as VARSTRING and not VARCHAR. Would expect a consistent type name from both Resultsets.

Example shown using SQLSquirrel

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `JDBC 1.0.1` driver to more stable version of JDBC or it might be a case that your `varchar(32)` 'data' exceeds its limit so the JDBC interpreted it as `VARSTRING`. Because JDBC converts the datatype in Result set metadata, usually when there is something wrong.